# 3D Vector Plan (How to find the equation of the plane)

Tags: vectors, 3d

The exercise is from HAESE MATHEMATICS HL (CORE) 3

My question is how do I find the equation of the plane when containing $A(3, 2, 1)$ and the line $x = 1 + t, y = 2 - t, z = 3 + 2t$.

Comment: What country is that textbook from? What have you tried?

Comment: quick answer : put $t=0$ and $t=-1$ on the line and find two points; with A now you have three points ..

Comment: Thank you G Cab.

So it should be like this right:
x+3y+z=3(1)+2(3)+1(1)
Reduced down
x+3y+z=10

But now I'm just interested in how you find the t-values?

Comment: By the way, the textbook is from Australia